# MongoDB updating an attribute in every object in a nested array

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to increment the `caps`attribute for every player on a given team in one go.

Each team is structured as below:

```
{
  name: "Real Madrid",
  players: [ { p_id: "Ronaldo", goal: 135, caps: 134, age: 28 },
             { p_id: "Bale", goal: 75, caps: 45, age: 27 },
             { p_id: "Marcelo", goal: 11, caps: 25, age: 31 },
          { p_id: "Benzema", goal: 125, caps: 95, age: 22 } 
  ]
}
```

I can only find instructions on how to update one nested record at a time.

```
db.teams.update({ name: "Real Madrid", "players.p_id" : Ronaldo },
{ $inc : { players.$.caps : 1 });
```

Can I update all records at once? I can

I will include solution here for others:

```
var bulk = db.teams.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),   
count = 0;

db.teams.find({ name: "Real Madrid" }).forEach( function(doc) {
var players = doc["players"];

    for( var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        bulk.find(
            {
                "_id": doc._id,
                "players" : { $elemMatch : { "goal" : players[i]["goal"] }}
            }).update({ 
                $inc : { "players.$.goal" : 3 } 
            });
    }

    bulk.execute();
});
```

Comment: You again have a typo between `players` and `player`

Comment: Editted again :) however, this isn't a solution. The above query still only updates one row at a time. I'm looking to update every player at once.

Comment: You mean that the first time you run it only `Ronaldo` is updated, and then the second time `Bale` is updated, etc? Or do you mean only one document (the one with `name: "Real Madrid"`) is updated at a time (but all elements in the array are updated).

Comment: Thanks David, the last link you shared explained that it can't be done how I'd hoped to do it.

Comment: @Rich131 your answer is in there. Please check the first link to the possible duplicate it does exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks user3100115, that helped!